# When I do a push instruction, I receive: Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, nasm

At the following code, when I un-comment any of the `push` instructions, I receive the error `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` while running the executable. I tried to pin-point the error cause, but the cause is not found yet.

```
section .data
; Message contains app purpose
msg db 'This app calculates 2^3+5^2',0x0a
mlen equ $-msg

msg1 db 'Computation is done',0x0a
lmsg1 equ $-msg1

num1 dd 2
lnum1 equ $-num1

pow1 dd 3
lpow1 equ $-pow1

num2 dd 5
lnum2 equ $-num2

pow2 dd 2
lpow2 equ $-pow2

section .text
global _start
_start:

    xor edx, edx ; clear registers
    xor ecx, ecx
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor eax, eax
    xor esi, esi
    xor edi, edi
    xor esp, esp
    xor ebp, ebp

    mov edx, mlen
    mov ecx, msg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80 ; print message

    mov edx, dword [pow2]
    mov ecx, dword [num2]
    mov ebx, dword [pow1]
    mov eax, dword [num1]
    ;push edx
    ;push ecx ; --> When I un-comment any push command,
    ;push ebx ; --> I receive: Segmentation fault (core dumped)
    ;push eax ;

    jmp end

end:
    mov edx, lmsg1      ; length
    mov ecx, msg1       ; memory location
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 0x80            ; print a newline i.e. 0x0a 

    mov ebx, 0
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

Comment: What is `push`ed must be `pop`ed, or you unbalance the stack. This is a common cause of seg faults. What is the purpose of the `push` instructions, anyway? What are you trying to do? Also, by the way, you don't need `imp end`; execution falls through to there anyway!

Comment: @CodyGray This code is just the beginning of developing a function to calculate some math. The `push` commands are preparing the arguments of the to-be-developed function

Comment: `xor esp, esp`  you zero out the stack pointer, duh. You do realize that's kinda bad if you want to use the stack, right?

Comment: @CodyGray Even if I do `pop edx` immediately after `push edx`, I receive the same error

Comment: @Jester That was it, I commented out the `xor esp, esp` and `xor ebp, ebp` lines and the problem got resolved. Thanks.

Comment: @Jester Well, I don't realize why that's bad if I'm not using stack pointer `now` but I'm going to use it a few instructions later

Comment: `push` will want to write to the stack, and stack is where `esp` points to. If you zero it out, that will give you a segfault when trying to use it, not at the time of zeroing.

Comment: @Jester Now I get it. It makes sense

Comment: Note: With ESP set to zero, a push of 4 bytes will cause it to wrap around to 0xFFFFFFFC and then store the 4 bytes. This address is in kernel space, so the push causes a page fault (CPL=3 code trying to write to supervisor pages). The page fault is converted to a signal (SIGSEGV), which leads to the `Segmentation fault` error message.

Comment: Stack is ordinary memory as any other, the `push/pop` are just convenience instructions, doing something similar like: `push eax` = `sub esp,4` `mov [esp],eax` (but `push` will not modify flags, and it is sort of more atomic, see instruction reference guide for the tiniest details... so it's not *exactly* the same thing).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect?
If you mess with the stackpointer (`esp`) obviously you are going to be in trouble.

On x86 protected mode address 0 is never a valid destination.
In addition all 'negative' addresses (0x80000000-0xFFFFFFFF) are in kernel space.

You reset `esp` and then you `push`, meaning you store a register in address `0-4 = 0xFFFFFFFC`. This will fail because your process in user space does not have access to kernel space.

Regardless of the details, you can never mess with `ESP` like that. Only ever increment or decrement `ESP` as needed to clear or create stack space.
Never set `esp` to an absolute address.

Comment: *On x86 protected mode address 0 is never a valid destination.* Not strictly true, but sane OSes *choose* not to map anything at that address, so NULL pointer deref faults noisily instead of silently loading or storing garbage.  So a useful simplification for running code under a mainstream OS.

Comment: In 32-bit code under a 64-bit kernel, your process has all 4GiB of virtual address space, except maybe the top page.  That's technically a different mode, compat sub-mode of long mode, not protected mode, but it's the normal way to run 32-bit mode these days.